# Boost asio ssl socket doesn't receive complete data different behaviour of tcp socket and ssl socket

Tags: c++, sockets, ssl, https, boost-asio

I'm using

```
boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket>
```

and

```
boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket
```

in a template method to receive data (HTTP(S)-POST-Request with data (multi-part)) from a Webbrowser (Firefox).

```
template<class SocketType>
void handleHTTPSRequest(SocketType& socket, ...........)
```

**My problem is, that the behaviour of this two sockets is different.**
In a loop:

```
av = socketAvailable(socket);
while(av == 0 || timeout...)
{
    av = socketAvailable(socket);
}
if(av > 2048)
{
    av = 2048;
}
recv = socket.read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buffer, av));
if(recv <= 0) // ignoring that recv is 0 doesn't help receiving the complete data.
{
    break; //and use data
}
```

*The data is not complete when I use*

```
boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket>
```

instead of

```
boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket
```

*which works for me.*

Comment: You should make the code self-contained. We can't tell what socketAvailable is doing. I have some general hunches based on the fact that _this_ is the code you chose to show, so see my answer.

Comment: There is nothing in your code that makes the data "complete". You just ask for "some" data and in both cases you get some data. If you want "complete" data, write code to get complete data, that is, get more data if you didn't get enough.

Comment: std::size_t socketAvailable
(boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket>& socket)

{

 return socket.next_layer().available();

}


std::size_t socketAvailable(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket& socket)

{

 return socket.available();

}

Answer (score 1):

> *You should make the code self-contained. We can't tell what `socketAvailable` is doing.*

However, in general just reading "whatever is available" is identical to "read_some" (given enough buffer) and is **never** a good way to receive the full request, because the organization and timing of the lower-layer packets are not something you can rely on.

You need to do [`read_until`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/read_until.html) or [`read`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/read.html) with "unbounded" buffer to read the full request.

### Demo Using Beast

Since you're using Boost, consider using Beast to read the request:

```
template <typename Stream>
void handle_request(Stream& s) {
    http::request<http::string_body> request;
    beast::flat_buffer buf;
    read(s, buf, request);

    std::cout << "The full request headers: " << request.base() << "\n";
    std::cout << "Body size is: " << request.body().length() << "\n";
    std::cout << "Trailing unused buffer data: " << buf.size() << "\n";

    // write body to a file
    std::ofstream("body.txt", std::ios::binary)
        << request.body();

    // be polite and respond
    auto res
        = http::response<http::string_body>(http::status::ok, 11, "Thanks\r\n");
    write(s, res);
}
```

This will work with any [AsyncReadStream](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/AsyncReadStream.html) - so a plain TCP socket as well as an SSL stream on top of one.

Let's add a test program that can use SSL optionally:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::set<std::string_view> const args(argv+1, argv+argc);
    bool const use_ssl = args.count("ssl");
    bool const single_request = args.count("single");
    net::io_context io;
    tcp::acceptor acc(io, {{}, 8099});

    while(true) {
        tcp::socket conn = acc.accept();

        if (!use_ssl) {
            handle_request(conn);
        } else {
            using Stream = beast::ssl_stream<tcp::socket>;
            using Ctx = ssl::context;
            Ctx ctx(Ctx::method::sslv23);
            ctx.use_certificate_file("server.pem", Ctx::pem);
            ctx.set_password_callback( [](size_t, Ctx::password_purpose) { return "test"; });
            ctx.use_rsa_private_key_file("server.pem", Ctx::pem);

            Stream s(std::move(conn), ctx);
            s.handshake(Stream::server);

            handle_request(s);
            s.shutdown();
        }

        if (single_request)
            break;
    }
}
```

Now, we can run it either in plain HTTP mode or HTTPS:

```sh
./sotest               # HTTP
./sotest ssl           # HTTPS
```

### Testing

Using a simple `curl` to send a multipart:

```
curl -X POST -k -F 'upload=@main.cpp' http://localhost:8099
curl -X POST -k -F 'upload=@main.cpp' https://localhost:8099
```

Both work as advertised, and curl prints the server response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Thanks
```

### Live Demo

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/484d72341faca19a)**

```
#include <boost/beast.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/http.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/ssl.hpp>
// for debug output only:
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <set>

namespace beast = boost::beast;
namespace http = beast::http;
namespace net = boost::asio;
namespace ssl = net::ssl;
using net::ip::tcp;
using boost::system::error_code;

template <typename Stream>
void handle_request(Stream& s) {
    http::request<http::string_body> request;
    beast::flat_buffer buf;
    read(s, buf, request);

    std::cout << "The full request headers: " << request.base() << "\n";
    std::cout << "Body size is: " << request.body().length() << "\n";
    std::cout << "Trailing unused buffer data: " << buf.size()              << "\n";

    // write body to a file
    std::ofstream("body.txt", std::ios::binary)
        << request.body();

    // be polite and respond
    auto res
        = http::response<http::string_body>(http::status::ok, 11, "Thanks\r\n");
    write(s, res);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::set<std::string_view> const args(argv+1, argv+argc);
    bool const use_ssl = args.count("ssl");
    bool const single_request = args.count("single");
    net::io_context io;
    tcp::acceptor acc(io, {{}, 8099});

    while(true) {
        tcp::socket conn = acc.accept();

        if (!use_ssl) {
            handle_request(conn);
        } else {
            using Stream = beast::ssl_stream<tcp::socket>;
            using Ctx = ssl::context;
            Ctx ctx(Ctx::method::sslv23);
            ctx.use_certificate_file("server.pem", Ctx::pem);
            ctx.set_password_callback( [](size_t, Ctx::password_purpose) { return "test"; });
            ctx.use_rsa_private_key_file("server.pem", Ctx::pem);

            Stream s(std::move(conn), ctx);
            s.handshake(Stream::server);

            handle_request(s);
            s.shutdown();
        }

        if (single_request)
            break;
    }
}
```

With the commands

```
g++ -std=c++17 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp -lssl -lcrypto -o sotest
(./sotest ssl single &
sleep 1
curl -s -i -X POST -k -F 'upload=@main.cpp' https://127.0.0.1:8099
wait)
```

The server prints

```
The full request headers: POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:8099
User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 2199
Expect: 100-continue
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------cdd7b913a4ef2f57

Body size is: 2199
Trailing unused buffer data: 0
```

And curl prints:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Thanks
```

> **Note** This uses [`server.pem`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/47f4f90a75a5f6b0) as included in the Asio examples for certificate/private key loading

Answer (score 0):

**Thanks for the detailed solution using beast.**

I have figured out another solution for my use case:

Missing code for socketAvailable

```
std::size_t socketAvailable(boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket>& socket)
{
    return socket.next_layer().available();
}

std::size_t socketAvailable(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket& socket)
{
    return socket.available();
}
```

My solution is working when the content-length is set in the request head:

```
knownreceivesize = contentLength + requestHeadSize (untill (including) \r\n\r\n)
```

`transferSize` is the number of bytes already been received from the request.

```
av = socketAvailable(server);

if(av > 2048)
{
    av = 2048;
}
if (knownreceivesize > 0 && av < knownreceivesize - transferSize)
{
    av = knownreceivesize-transferSize;
    if (av > 2048)
    {
        av = 2048;
    }
}
```

Comment: The usual way to write this would be to keep a "remaining" bytes count and then just read with a fixed 2048 byte buffer buffer. No need to do maths that way (Also less risk of unsigned integer wrap-around bugs).